# Nuget slow updating references after clean?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

This is what my refs look like...

[image]

If I do a clean and build on the project or my solution it will fail to build because the clean has removed the refs to the Nuget packages we use (Moq and NUnit.Framework)...

[image]

Rebuilding the project doesn't fix things, however if I **rebuild** the solution the package refs will be available again, and the build will succeed.

**Weirdly** this doesn't happen on the other unit tests project in this solution. Its refs to MOQ and NUnit remain intact after a clean, even thought they have been added via Nuget in the same way. I suspect I have missed something stupid but for the life of me I can't work it out.

**EDIT:** In preparing the images for this update I noticed the symptoms aren't exactly as I thought, so I have expanded the problem description.

Comment: A clean should not remove the package.  Be specific about which one you use.

Comment: Try to click on your reference, press F4, and set "Copy Local" to "False".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it!**

I opened both csproj files and found that the hint paths for the same assemblies were different in the two files. The good project is referencing `packages` where as the bad project is referenceing the good (`Delivery.Website.UnitTests`) project.

So to fix...

```
<Reference Include="Moq">
  <HintPath>..\Delivery.Website.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Moq.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\Delivery.Website.UnitTests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

...becomes...

```
<Reference Include="Moq">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.2\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

...and it works like it should!

No idea how it got into this state in the first place though :\